# How does this oscillator circuit with a transformer work?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, inductor, oscillator, npn

I know it is an oscillator circuit but I don't know how it works. This circuit is supposed turn the LED on and off continuously. Can you please explain it to me? The star sign in the figure is not connected.

[image: I know its an oscillator circuit but i don't know how it works. This circuit is supposed turn ON and OFF led continuously. can you please explain me ?The star sign in figure is not connected.]

When the switch is connected, the current flows through the resistor and because of it the transistor turns on  and current flows through the inductor and the LED turns on. How does the LED turn off and then turn on again?

Comment: Please provide source of circuit and its intended purpose.

Comment: Sorry I forget to attach image but now I attached

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried to simulate the circuit?

Comment: How fast is your circuit oscillating?

Comment: I must say that the "X" between the cap/transformer net and the resistor/transformer net is very very very confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Simulated with some "difficulties" with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110).

I added a diode + Zener to simulate inverse B-E "breakdown" at ~ 5 V.
I used a ferrite model 2P40, **tight coupling** (don't know if it does work with another model).
I changed the capacitor to 1 uF ... (because of the "very long" simulation, max step time = 1 us).

[image]

There are three phases in the behavior.

**Phase 1** : vb is negative, Q1 is off, charge of capacitor exponentially through the resistor until vb "should" be equal to 9 V ...

**Phase 2** : when vb ~> 0.6 V, Q1 become on, instantaneous current increase in L2 ...

**Phase 3** : current decrease then stops, voltage negative appears in L1 which does push the vb negative until breakdown at - 5 V ...
this is quasi "intantaneous" done ...

NB: phase 3 is a "little" more complicated.  Details of the current pulse.

[image]

Then **phase 1** ...

Comment: Can you please explain it ? I am getting confused so

Comment: Added in answer ...

Answer (score 1):

The center-tap of the transformer is common at +9V and the base and collector have opposite signal polarities. Then the transistor has positive feedback and oscillates.

Comment: Can you please explain it more?

Answer (score 1):

A transistor amplifier is an inverter. When its input (base) is high its output (collector) is low. In other words there is a phase shift of 180 degrees.

An oscillator is an amplifier with sufficient positive feedback (in the same phase as the input) to sustain oscillations.

The circuit in question is that of an LC audio oscillator. The LC oscillator uses a transformer for feedback. Since the amplifier has a phase shift of 180◦, the feedback transformer provides the required additional phase shift of 180◦ for positive feedback.